# Characterization of quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following characterization of quotient topology:

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$, $\sigma$ a topology in the quotient space $X/\sim$, $\tau_{\sim}$ the quotient topology and $q: X \longrightarrow X/\sim$ the canoncial map.
>
> Then, $\sigma = \tau_\sim$ if, and only if, for every toplogocial space $(Y, \tau_Y)$ and any continuous function $g: (X, \tau) \longrightarrow (Y, \tau_Y)$ such that $x \sim y$ implies $g(x) = g(y)$, there exists a **unique** continuous function $f: (X/\sim, \sigma)  \rightarrow (Y, \tau_Y)$ such that $g= f \circ q$.

I've managed to prove that *if* $\sigma = \tau_\sim$ then the universal property is satisfied.

Furthermore, for the reverse implication I've proven that, taking $(Y, \tau_y) = (X/\sim, \tau_\sim)$ and $g=q$, that the unique $f: (X/\sim, \sigma)  \rightarrow (X/\sim, \tau_\sim)$ must be the identity and, as it is continuous, $\tau_\sim$ is contained in $\sigma$.

Now, I'm stuck trying to see the other inclusion, that is, that $\sigma$ is also contained in $\tau_\sim$.

Could anyone give some hints on how to prove this?

Comment: You're *not* assuming that $\sigma$ makes $q$ continuous? That would be costumary...

Comment: If we assume that $\sigma$ makes $q$ continuous then the inclusion $\sigma \subset \tau_\sim$ is clear and the proof is finished. Maybe it is necessary to assume that, but I was trying to prove it without that assumption.

Comment: It might very well be necessary.